# Using CURL for GET request

Tags: c++, curl, minecraft

I got this nasty problem with my minecraft server program.
I try to get login response from minecraft.com when you try to login to my minecraft server. Everything is fine and setup like verify token key and shared secret.

I just can't get the get request to work with curl :(

This is what I have:

```
    requestString.append("GET /session/minecraft/hasJoined?username=");
    requestString.append(player.Username);
    requestString.append("&");
    requestString.append("serverId=");
    requestString.append(player.loginHash);
    requestString.append(" HTTP/1.0\r\n");
    std::cout << requestString << std::endl;


    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sessionserver.mojang.com");
    list = curl_slist_append(list, requestString.c_str());
    list = curl_slist_append(list, "User-Agent: MinecraftServerPP\r\n");
    list = curl_slist_append(list, "Connection: close\r\n");
    list = curl_slist_append(list, "\r\n");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cacert.pem");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &_write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
```

I get an ok from the server, but not the json object containing the data I need.

Comment: When *everything* is fine ? Using command line cURL ? If yes, post it. I don't really get why you are sending `GET / .... ` on your header request.

Comment: Use `strace` to capture the raw request being sent to the server. Compare to the request that should be sent. Then figure out how to make your request match what should be sent. P.S. with all the work this code is doing I don't understand why curl is even needed. You've done all the work. Just create a socket, connect to the server, write the request, read the response. Done.

Comment: This is not command line curl. I use C++. And this is a other version i tried. The first one was with "CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS". The problem was that i get the error "the request could not be satisfied"

Comment: I am thinking about doing that Sam Varshavchik

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you putting the `GET` request line in the HTTP headers?  It does not belong there at all, and in fact the libCURL documentation even points that out:

[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER explained](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.html)

> The first line in a request (containing the method, usually a GET or POST) **is not a header** and cannot be replaced using this option. **Only the lines following the request-line are headers. Adding this method line in this list of headers will only cause your request to send an invalid header**. Use CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST to change the method.

Your current code is sending a `GET` request similar to this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: sessionserver.mojang.com
GET /session/minecraft/hasJoined?username=<username>&serverId=<loginHash> HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: MinecraftServerPP
Connection: close
```

Which is why you are not getting the response you are expecting.  You are not actually requesting the `/session/minecraft/hasJoined` resource, you are actually requesting the root `/` resource.

You should be sending a `GET` request like this instead:

```
GET /session/minecraft/hasJoined?username=<username>&serverId=<loginHash> HTTP/1.0
Host: sessionserver.mojang.com
User-Agent: MinecraftServerPP
Connection: close
```

To accomplish that, you need to pass the *complete* URL to `CURLOPT_URL` and let libCURL handle the `GET` line for you.  You can use [`CURLOPT_HTTPGET`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPGET.html) to ensure that `GET` is actually used.

Also, you should be using [`CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION.html) if you want to specify a specific HTTP version.

Also, although you *can* use `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` for the `User-Agent` and `Connection` headers, you *should* be using [`CURLOPT_USERAGENT`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_USERAGENT.html) and [`CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE.html) instead.

Try this instead:

```
url = "https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/hasJoined?username=");
url.append(player.Username); // <-- NOTE: see further below!
url.append("&serverId=");
url.append(player.loginHash); // <-- NOTE: see further below!
std::cout << url << std::endl;

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1L); 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cacert.pem");

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MinecraftServerPP");

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &_write_data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
```

Now, with that said, there is additional logic you need to take into account to handle [`CURLOPT_URL`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_URL.html) *correctly*:

> Pass in a pointer to the URL to work with. The parameter should be a char * to a zero terminated string **which must be URL-encoded** in the following format:
>
> scheme://host:port/path
>
> For a greater explanation of the format please see [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).
>
> libcurl doesn't validate the syntax or use this variable until the transfer is issued. Even if you set a crazy value here, `curl_easy_setopt` will still return `CURLE_OK`.

In particular, these sections of the RFC are relevant to your code:

> 2.1.  Percent-Encoding
>
> **A percent-encoding mechanism is used to represent a data octet in a component when that octet's corresponding character is outside the allowed set** or is being used as a delimiter of, or within, the component.  A percent-encoded octet is encoded as a character triplet, consisting of the percent character "%" followed by the two hexadecimal digits representing that octet's numeric value.  For example, "%20" is the percent-encoding for the binary octet "00100000" (ABNF: %x20), which in US-ASCII corresponds to the space character (SP).  **[Section 2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.4) describes when percent-encoding and decoding is applied.**
>
> pct-encoded = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
>
> The uppercase hexadecimal digits 'A' through 'F' are equivalent to the lowercase digits 'a' through 'f', respectively.  If two URIs differ only in the case of hexadecimal digits used in percent-encoded octets, they are equivalent.  For consistency, URI producers and normalizers should use uppercase hexadecimal digits for all percent-encodings.

> 2.4.  When to Encode or Decode
>
> **Under normal circumstances, the only time when octets within a URI are percent-encoded is during the process of producing the URI from its component parts.  This is when an implementation determines which of the reserved characters are to be used as subcomponent delimiters and which can be safely used as data.  Once produced, a URI is always in its percent-encoded form.**
>
> When a URI is dereferenced, the components and subcomponents significant to the scheme-specific dereferencing process (if any) must be parsed and separated before the percent-encoded octets within those components can be safely decoded, as otherwise the data may be mistaken for component delimiters.  The only exception is for percent-encoded octets corresponding to characters in the unreserved set, which can be decoded at any time.  For example, the octet corresponding to the tilde ("~") character is often encoded as "%7E" by older URI processing implementations; the "%7E" can be replaced by "~" without changing its interpretation.
>
> Because the percent ("%") character serves as the indicator for percent-encoded octets, it must be percent-encoded as "%25" for that octet to be used as data within a URI.  Implementations must not percent-encode or decode the same string more than once, as decoding an already decoded string might lead to misinterpreting a percent data octet as the beginning of a percent-encoding, or vice versa in the case of percent-encoding an already percent-encoded string.

The `query` component of a URL is defined in [section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4):

> query       = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )

`pchar` is defined in [section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3):

> pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"

`unreserved` is defined in [section 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.3):

> unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"

`sub-delims` is defined in [section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2):

> sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="

So, if any characters in your `player.Username` and `player.loginHash` strings
are *outside of these allowed characters*, you **MUST** percent-encode them when putting them into your URL's query string.  For example:

```
std::string encodeForUrlQuery(std::string s)
{
    static const char* allowed = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/?";

    // this is just an example, in practice you should first convert the
    // input string to Unicode and charset-encode it, usually to UTF-8,
    // and then percent-encode the resulting octets...

    std::string::size_type idx = s.find_first_not_of(allowed);
    while (idx != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << '%' << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::uppercase << (int)s[idx];
        std::string encoded = oss.str();
        s.replace(idx, 1, encoded);
        idx = s.find_first_not_of(allowed, idx+encoded.length());
    }
    return s;
}
```

```
url = "https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/hasJoined?username=");
url.append(encodeForUrlQuery(player.Username));
url.append("&serverId=");
url.append(encodeForUrlQuery(player.loginHash));
std::cout << url << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thank You for this detailed answer. I will try your suggestions